# I have a 2015 Nissan Rogue my heater wasn't working so I changed my water pump and now I have oil in my radiator until this happened I had NO oil leak

Tags: oil, radiator, water, pump

I just changed the water pump in my Nissan Rogue because my heater wasn't working and now I have oil in my radiator but no anti freeze in my oil what could be causing it? My car didn't leak oil until this happened

Answer (score 0):

You may have a blown head gasket. Do a cylinder leakdown test to either confirm or eliminate that possibility before replacing any more parts.